# Can't display character "€" of text on Google Maps (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

On Google Maps of Android and iOS, I can't display character "€" on text of maps.

[Image_Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCqf6.png)

- This is my code, I use class `Pin.cs` of `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps`:

  ```
  private Pin ConvertToPropertyMapPinModel(Bucket<int> target, CultureInfo info)
  {
     var address = new List<string>();
     address.Add($"Price: €110,551");

      var pin = new Pin
      {
          Label = property.PropertyReference,
          Address = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, address),
          Position = new Position(property.GoogleX, property.GoogleY),
          Icon = stream != null ? BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromStream(stream) : null,
      };
      SetPropertyProperty(pin, property);
      return pin;
  }
  ```

Please support me!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain the compiler is using the right encoding for your source file? If you change your source code to `address.Add("Price: \u20AC110,551");` does that work?

Comment: That character is the [Unicode replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), used only when *non*-Unicode text is converted to Unicode using the wrong codepage. This means that your source file was *not* saved as UTF8. Save your file using the UTF8 encoding. This is the default in Visual Studio for quite some time now.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "`€`" is a special character.

If you want to add it in a string, you should use Unicode.

[Unicode characters table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html)

The character "`€`" has Unicode is `U+20AC`

**Ps**: You can also add emoji to strings

[Full Emoji List](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f6b4)

Comment: It works! I asked it 6 months ago. But your answer is very full. Thanks for your support!